# Крымская Ницца - это Ялта. Как писать?

Tags: выбор-слов, выбор

Крымская Ницца – это Ялта, ее так называют. Как писать? Интересует вопрос по поводу написания слова «крымская». Склоняюсь к тому, что с маленькой буквы....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как правильно выбрать форму записи для названий**

1. Сначала определимся, что мы выбираем. Существуют **четыре формы письма**, обозначенные в правилах: два варианта для собственных имен (прописная буква)  и два варианта для нарицательных имен (строчная буква).

**Собственные имена** – это официальное  название (по документации)  или упрощенное (общеупотребительное название). **Нарицательное имя**  может заключаться в кавычки  (обозначение условности)  или же писаться без кавычек, если оно общеизвестно и обозначено в словаре.

**От чего зависит выбор формы?** От множества факторов, их и не счесть: от смысла, от предложения, от контекста, от стиля, даже от времени написания данного текста.

2. **Рассмотрим наш пример.**

Три предполагаемые формы:  (1) Крымская Ницца; (2) крымская Ницца; (3) «крымская Ницца».

**Какой здесь смысл**, Ницца – это символ чего? Самый известный и фешенебельный курорт или еще что-то?  В Крыму много красивых городов, разве одна Ялта может претендовать  на такое название? Скорее всего, не все так думают. А если и так, то это должно быть ясно из текста.

4. Можно ли приравнять наш случай **к Северной Пальмире.** Это – условное иносказание, которое зафиксировано в разных письменных источниках и словарях, на него уже никто не может претендовать (там полная однозначность).  Следовательно,  писать прописную букву в нашем случае нет оснований.
5. **А кавычки?** Это уже решается с учетом предложения, текста, стиля. Даже в одной статье возможны разные написания в зависимости от того, первый раз мы используем название или повторяем его. У нас же только часть предложения:  *«…в этом уголке крымской Ниццы есть все для великолепного отдыха....»* . Это вообще похоже **на мнение автора**, тогда писать без условных кавычек – это слишком смелый шаг.
6. Остается такое написание: ***«…в этом уголке «крымской Ниццы»  есть все для великолепного отдыха....»*** . Это выглядит **как скрытое сравнение** Ялты с Ниццой, как прием художественной выразительности, не более того.  Но для окончательного решения надо видеть всю статью.

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от того, в каком смысле употребляет словосочетание «К(к)рымская Ялта» автор текста. Если автор имеет в виду неофициальное прозвище Ялты (и тут ещё надо быть уверенным, что все или хотя бы подавляющее большинство его читателей знают о существовании такого прозвища, — а, например, я о нём до сих пор не знал), то оно должно быть не только с прописной буквы, но, пожалуй, и в кавычках. Если Ялта для автора именно *крымская*, *находящаяся в Крыму* Ницца, то это словосочетание подаётся им как собственная мысль: *я считаю, что Ялта — крымская Ницца, и другие её тоже так называют.*

Или, если вы не хотите давать Ялте такое титулирование от своего имени, можно и вариант со строчной взять в кавычки: «Ялта — это "крымская Ницца", её так называют».

А ещё можно поставить словосочетание в начало фразы, и проблемы вообще не будет :)

Comment: «...я считаю, что Ялта — крымская Ницца, и другие её тоже так называют». Вот я тоже так хочу написать.....режет мне Крымская Ницца....

Comment: Кстати, вон и Eagle поставил «Азиатский Лас-Вегас» в кавычки. А если без кавычек, то со строчной, — я так «щитаю» :)

Comment: Надо определить степень устойчивости выражения – сосчитать всех считающих. На первом этапе поставить кавычки, а потом уже можно и так.  :)) А вообще-то все зависит от конкретного предложения в конкретном тексте, вот его и желательно процитировать.

Comment: ...«в этом уголке крымской Ниццы есть все для великолепного отдыха....»

Comment: Я бы так написала: ..«в этом уголке "крымской Ниццы" есть все для великолепного отдыха....»  Условность выражения обозначаем кавычками. Здесь это не имя собственное, чтобы писать с прописной буквы. Название сложно отнести к общепринятому иносказанию, как Северную Пальмиру.  И "азиатский Лас-Вегс", кстати, тоже.

Comment: @flossyU _«в этом уголке крымской Ниццы есть все для великолепного отдыха»_ Так можно было бы написать, если бы в Крыму действительно был город Ницца. Бывает, что города с одинаковым названием есть в разных местах. Например, есть Барселона в Испании и Венесуэле. Тогда _испанская Барселона_, чтоб понятно было о какой Барселоне идёт речь. В данном случае никакой Ниццы в Крыму нет. Поэтому «крымская Ницца» — неправильно. Крымская Ницца — это неофициальное устойчивое образное название города и пишется оно с большой буквы.

Comment: @Sharon А почему не имя собственное, если это название города, пусть даже неофициальное, но название? Это как кличка. Например, слово «косой» — не имя собственное, но если это станет кличкой человека, то будет писаться с большой буквы: «Привет, Косой!».

Comment: @Sharon Я ещё раз повторюсь. Если мы будем писать с маленькой буквы «крымская Ницца», то получается, что в Крыму на самом деле есть Ницца. Бывает, что города с одинаковым названием есть в разных местах. Например, есть Барселона в Испании и Венесуэле. Тогда «испанская Барселона», чтоб понятно было о какой Барселоне идёт речь. В данном случае никакой Ниццы в Крыму нет. Поэтому «крымская Ницца» — неправильно. Крымская Ницца — это неофициальное устойчивое образное название города и пишется оно с большой буквы.

Comment: @Sharon Вот ответ gramota.ru на вопрос: _«[У Нью-Йорка есть прозвище — „Большое яблоко“. Скажите, как правильно его писать?](http://web.archive.org/web/20100625023835/http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords/25_350)»_.

Comment: Здесь  не тот вариант, что в вопросе. Прозвища, как и имена, пишутся с прописной буквы, так как это имена собственные. В нашем же случае условность уже есть, а имени собственного пока еще нет. Кстати, я ваши с Егором старания оценила голосом, а автор вопроса ничего вам не поставил, ага? Кавычек здесь вполне достаточно, а прописная буква - уже перебор.

Comment: flossyU, я дописал ответ.

Comment: @Sharon _«Название сложно отнести к общепринятому иносказанию»_  Данное словосочетание есть в книге 1896 https://books.google.com.ua/books?hl=ru&id=r0pQAQAAIAAJ&dq=%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%86%D0%B0&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%86%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо писать с большой буквы: Крымская Ницца.

> § 174. **В неофициальных устойчивых, в том числе образных, названиях**
> государств и **городов с прописной буквы пишется первое** (или
> единственное) **слово, а также (если они есть) собственные имена**,
> напр.: *Московское государство (ист.), Российское государство; Страна
> восходящего солнца (о Японии), Страна утренней свежести (о Корее),
> Поднебесная империя или Поднебесная (об императорском Китае), Страна
> кленового листа (о Канаде), Страна тюльпанов (о Голландии), Вечный
> город (о Риме), Белокаменная, Первопрестольная (о Москве), **Северная
> Пальмира (о Петербурге)**.*
>
> [[Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации полный академический справочник, редактор В. В. Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=84)]

Comment: так это Ницца, которая находится в Крыму, потому и крымская..... Как, например, азиатский Лас-Вегас - Макао.... Почему он должен писаться Азиатский Лас-Вегас...Это его место нахождения....

Comment: @flossyU А Северная Пальмира — это Пальмира, которая находится на севере, потому надо писать с маленькой буквы?

Comment: Это не то..... Если уж на то пошло, есть места посевернее, чем Петербург.... Название устоявшееся...

Comment: @flossyU Почему не то? При чём тут, есть места посевернее или нет? И то и то устойчивое неофициальное название, поэтому пишется с большой буквы.

Comment: По-вашему, Азиатский Лас-Вегас будет писаться?

Comment: @flossyU С большой буквы, если это устойчивое неофициальное название.

Comment: @@flossyU [National Geographic Россия](https://nat-geo.ru/travel/ngtraveler/makao-kitayskiy-las-vegas/): «Её называют „Азиатский Лас-Вегас“, но китайский аналог давно обогнал американский оригинал по объёму выручки».